# Springboot H2 in memory database - cannot connect

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have configured H2 as follows for my springboot app:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

When I go to log in it says it cannot find the database. I am typing explicitly `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` like this:

[image]

What else can I do to troubleshoot? I do have a data.sql file which is creating the schema and putting in sample data.

Comment: remove all the configurations except `spring.h2.console.enabled=true` and give it a try

Comment: Is it works without `data.sql` and `schema.sql`?

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem. adding jdbc and jpa to the pom.xml did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I read through some other tutorials which mentioned including `jdbc` or `jpa` in maven/gradle. When I added either of these then H2 seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problems, what I did to make this work was:

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:uniqueNewName <<testdb did not work!
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
springspring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
        <version>19.8.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Don't ask me why, but I had to add jbdc and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to my dependencies to make this work.